# How to unpickle sklearn.tree.DescisionTreeRegressor in python 2 from python3

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

How to unpickle sklearn.tree.DescisionTreeRegressor in python 2 from python3

> Saving Pickle file in python 3

from joblib import dump, load

dump(rfc, 'rfc.joblib',protocol = 2)

> loading Pickle file in python 2.7.14

from joblib import dump, load

rfc = load('rfc.joblib')

[image]

## Tried following and it is giving me classes and not the model

```
from lib2to3.fixes.fix_imports import MAPPING
REVERSE_MAPPING={}
for key,val in MAPPING.items():
    REVERSE_MAPPING[val]=key

class Python_3_Unpickler(pickle.Unpickler):
    """Class for pickling objects from Python 3"""
    def find_class(self,module,name):
        if module in REVERSE_MAPPING:
            module=REVERSE_MAPPING[module]
        import(module)
        mod = sys.modules[module]
        klass = getattr(mod, name)
        return klass

    def loads(str):
        file = pickle.StringIO(str)
        return Python_3_Unpickler(file).load()


with open('JULY_18_rfc_python_2.pkl', 'rb') as file_:
    rfc = Python_3_Unpickler(file_).load()
```